# Trying to change some Woocommerce default words and sentences

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing my first Wordpress/Woocommerce site, and I want to change some words in the default Wordpress translation of the site, in order to better suit the type of business. Currently I'm using the following code on the functions.php file of my theme (a Storefront's child theme):

```
add_filter('gettext', 'noProducto');

function noProducto($translated) {

    $default = array ('Descripción del producto', 'Productos relacionados');  

    $desired = array ('Descripción del inmueble', 'Inmuebles similares');    

$translated = str_ireplace($default, $desired , $translated);

return $translated;
}
```

It works, but I have read that this is not very efficient and could lead to performance problems. I want to use the recommended method instead:

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Descripción del producto' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Descripción del inmueble', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
        case 'Productos relacionados' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Inmuebles similares', 'woocommerce' );
            break;

    }
    return $translated_text;
};
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

However, it does not work for me, and I don't know why.
I'm new to Wordpress and I'm trying to learn good practices; so any hint on why the second method might not be working, will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.This will translate the text.

```
function mycustom_filter_gettext( $translated, $original, $domain ) {

    // This is an array of original strings
    // and what they should be replaced with
    $strings = array(
               'Related Products'=>'products'

    );

    // See if the current string is in the $strings array
    // If so, replace its translation
    if ( isset( $strings[$original] ) ) {

        $translations = get_translations_for_domain( $domain );
        $translated = $translations->translate( $strings[$original] );
    }

    return $translated;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'mycustom_filter_gettext', 10, 3 );
```